# Changes on published apps

Tags: android, google-play

If I publish a paid app in Google Play:

- In the future, can I make it free with in-app-purchases? (I know once it is free, I cannot revert it to a paid app).

If I publish a free app:

- Is it allowed to eliminate some features? (for example, in order to publish those features in a premium app...)

Some of these changes can be unproductive, I only want to know if they is allowed, I haven't found any legal stuff about this so I suppose it is possible but.... )

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will answer your question :

> 1. Decide Whether your App will be Free or Priced
>
> On Google Play, you can publish apps as free to download or priced.
>   Free apps can be downloaded by any Android user in Google Play. Paid
>   apps can be downloaded only by users who are in a country that
>   supports paid downloads and have registered a form of payment in
>   Google Play, such as a credit card or Direct Carrier Billing.
>
> Deciding whether you apps will be free or paid is important because,
>   on Google Play, free apps must remain free.
>
> **Once you publish an app as a free app, you cannot change it to being a
>   priced app. However, you can still sell in-app products and
>   subscriptions through Google Play's In-app Billing service**. If you
>   publish your app as a priced app, you can change it at any time to be
>   a free app (but cannot then change it back to priced). **You can also
>   sell in-app products and subscriptions**. If your app is be priced, or
>   if you'll be selling in-app products, **you need set up a Google Wallet
>   Merchant Account** before you can publish.

Comment: Thanks @harvey-slash. But how about the possibility to eliminate some features of an existing free app to put it on a premium add? It is legally allowed? 

In summary, what obligations exist about maintain features in next versions of the app? (wether it is free or paid).

Comment: by 'add' , do you mean an advertisment(ad)  ?

Comment: the next version of the app has to be FREE, but it can contain premium features like in-app purchases, as well as ads

Comment: Sorry, by "add" I wanted to say "app"

Comment: you can take any feature from your free app and put it in your paid app, as long as the premium app has a different package name(basically it means, its a new app)