# Lack of permission to publish change

Tags: google-workspace, gmail-addons

we need help to be able to publish some changes to our gmail addon configuration.

The original developer who submitted the addon for review has since left the company. Now I need to make some changes to the marketplace listing for the gmail addon, because the logo icon images are broken. Fill out the google form to "**request access**" here https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/appsmarket-component.googleapis.com/googleapps_sdk?project=citric-celerity-000&folder&organizationId , then told to come here for more help.

[image]

Might be related to this issue
[Changes on published apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24732479/changes-on-published-apps)

Comment: Did you try to follow the "request access" link?

Comment: Yes I did, I fill out the form, but it then got an email suggesting that I reach out here or file a bug in the issue tracker.